# SQL "DELETE FROM ... " doesn't work because elastic pool is full

Tags: sql-delete, azure-elasticpool

I'm trying to remove some rows from my table, because the elastic pool (Azure) is full. However, apparently deleting doesn't work when the pool is full.

I'm trying to run this statement in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS):

```
DELETE FROM [xx].[xxx] WHERE somecolumn = 13
```

But this returns:

> Msg 1132, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The elastic pool has reached its storage limit. The storage usage for the elastic pool cannot exceed (524288) MBs.

How do I get out of this situation?

Solutions that are not preferred/possible:

- Increasing the elastic pool size as it's already at its maximum
- Dropping the entire table, because there is relevant data in there

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried shrinking the database?

Comment: In another post I also found that option, but I wasn't sure what it exactly means. I was a little bit worried that it could lead to the loss of some data. That's why I didn't go for that option, I need to inform myself more on "DBCC SHRINKDATABASE".

Comment: I succeeded deleting data with the following workaround: I exported another table first (as a back-up). Then I removed that table from the elastic pool. This made some space free to make my delete statement work.